# How to extract a certain column in a space-delimited .txt file and store each unique value along with the number of times it appears [Unix - Bash]

Tags: bash, unix, awk

**The column that would be extracted is assumed to contain numerical values**

I'm not sure about the best strategy to accomplish this.

I was thinking to first extract the column and store the values in an array of some sort. Then loop over it and remove all values that are not unique, while also keeping track of how many of that value there are and storing this amount in a seperate array. So, there would be one array with each unique number, and a corresponding array with the amount of that number found in the original column?

What I have so far (grabs the second column from .txt and stores each row value in array (one per index)):

```
vals=($(awk '{print $2}' test.txt))
```

I am not sure how I should store
each unique value along with the number of times it appears, I think I would need something similar to a dictionary?

I know I can use sort and uniq to remove values that are not unique, but then I don't know how to count the total occurrences of each value.

sample .txt file that would be used

```
George 82 56 55
Martin 22 56 21
Cole 22 49 102
```

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Also, as this is not a free coding service, we'd appreciate seeing some attempt first. Thanks.

Comment: added some information, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk '{print $2}'` extracts the second *column*, not row.

You can indeed use `sort` and `uniq` to do this, and that's the traditional Unix 'toolbox' method, which a great many people before you have also thought of:

```
awk '{print $2}' file.txt | sort -n | uniq -c
```

(`uniq -c` counts adjacent duplicates instead of removing them. On any non-weird Unix system, you can use `man {programname}` to get documentation on a program, and `man uniq` shows you several options that can be useful for various things including `-c`.)

But `awk` can also do the whole job (or nearly) by itself:

```
awk '{++c[$2]} END{for(v in c){print c[v],v}}' file.txt
```

awk has 'associative' arrays subscripted or 'keyed' by any values, not just more-or-less consecutive integers; this was the 1970s name for what nowadays is often called a dictionary. (And all array elements, and variables other than predefined ones like NR NF OFS etc, are initialized to an empty value, which is treated numerically as zero.)

Since this is normally implemented as a hash-table, the `for..in` statement in traditional awk can produce the values in an arbitrary order, and the standard (POSIX) codifies this. If you want them in numeric order (as the `sort|uniq` method produces), you can add `... | sort -nk2`, or only on non-ancient versions of *GNU* awk (which is now common but not universal) you can use:

```
awk '{++c[$2]} END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc";for(v in c){print c[v],v}}' file.txt
```